# How can I get the top-most viewController when it implements multiple other classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So far I've been able to get the top-most (the visible) viewController reliably using the following code:

```
UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
while (topController.presentedViewController) {
    topController = topController.presentedViewController;
}
//topController.class now contains the name of my top viewController
//I can, for example, check if my contact list view is visible to the user with:
if (topController.class == [ContactViewController class]) {
    [viewTitle setText:@"Contacts"];
}
```

This is pretty easy, and also pretty awesome to use. My problem is that I try to detect if the following class is the top viewController

```
@interface GalleryViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
```

topController.class is now not equal to `[GalleryViewController class]` as it would be with all my other viewControllers. Instead, when I use the debugger to check the value it is `(_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController *)` with a random memory address (All the other viewControllers show up as (Class)ContactViewController with a random memory address).

Why does this specific class show up with such a weird name, is that because of the definition or is it something else? Also, how can I get the top most viewController properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make sure that you actually on the top most window with this snippet

```
UIWindow *topWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIWindow *win1, UIWindow *win2) {
    return win1.windowLevel - win2.windowLevel;
}] lastObject];
```

Comment: How do I use this snippet to get the 'right' window?

Comment: I replaced '[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow' with 'topWindow' and it works :). Thanks! Turns out it was caused by an alertview that opened right before navigating to the new view.